# Formatei o PC do Windows 10 para o Linux ubuntu, após baixar um projeto do git e ter atualizado o mesmo, como dar um commit em outra main?

Tags: linux, github

Formatei o PC do Windows 10 para o Linux ubuntu, após baixar um projeto do git e ter atualizado o mesmo, como dar um commit em outra main?

Tentei git branch não deu, git checkout -b também não, preciso atualizar o repositório.

Answer (score -3):

Antes de tudo, é importante verificar se o repositório que você baixou tem uma branch `main` já existente. Se sim, você pode mudar para a branch principal utilizando o comando `git checkout <nome-da-branch>`.

Em seguida, é necessário adicionar as alterações que você fez no projeto com o comando `git add <arquivos-modificados>`. Depois disso, você pode dar um commit utilizando o comando `git commit -m "Mensagem de commit"`.

Observação: o comando `checkout` com a flag `-b`, é usado para criar uma nova branch baseada na branch ativa atualmente.

Em resumo, os passos são:

1. Verificar se existe uma branch `main` já criada
2. Mudar para a branch `main` ou criar uma branch
3. Adicionar as alterações
4. Dar um commit com uma mensagem descritiva.

Espero que essas informações ajudem você a dar um commit.
Lembrando que só é possível ter uma branch por nome, por exemplo, não podemos ter mais de uma branch com o nome `main`.

Caso ainda tenha dúvidas, você pode consultar a documentação oficial do Git (https://git-scm.com/docs).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).